# How to execute any external windows command with multiple parameter using python

Tags: python, command

I need to execute the command below using python but unable to execute:

```
cmd="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe" -classpath ./;sqljdbc4.jar InsertTestIncidentData -h 172.20.240.57 -p 1433 -u sa -w Recnex#1 -d ePO_WINEP02 -n 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd='"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe" -classpath ./;sqljdbc4.jar InsertTestIncidentData -h 172.20.240.57 -p 1433 -u sa -w Recnex#1 -d ePO_WINEP02 -n 10'
```

You can use `os.system`:

```
 import os
 os.system(cmd)
```

or with subprocess:

```
import subprocess
ret=subprocess.Popen([cmd])
print "Returning status",ret.wait()
```

if you are verifying some output from your command:

```
import subprocess
output=subprocess.chec_call([cmd])
```

Comment: thanks....but i need exit status of command along with the output, like we get 0 and 1 in case of os.system(cmd).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

cmd='"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe" -classpath ./;sqljdbc4.jar InsertTestIncidentData -h 172.20.240.57 -p 1433 -u sa -w Recnex#1 -d ePO_WINEP02 -n 10'
os.system(cmd)
```

Since there's a whitespace in `Program Files`, you should quote the path with another double quote.